# GA4 to BigQuery historic backfill

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

I've set up a Google Analytics 4 (GA4) to BigQuery data transfer. The [docs](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3437618?hl=en&ref_topic=3416089#zippy=%2Ccompare-bigquery-export-in-google-analytics-and-universal-analytics) state that backfilling data is not possible for GA4, as previously possible for UA. As far as I can tell, the Analytics Data API does not provide event-level data. Is there anyway I can backfill the data? Via API scripts, or some GCP native functionality that I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 3):

You are correct that:

1. Backfilling was supported for GA360 customers for Universal Analytics (UA) properties.
2. Data API does not provide any event level data.

However, currently (March 2023), there is no official way to backfill BigQuery event data for GA4 properties.

Comment: Thank you! Are you aware if allowing GA4 backfilling is planned for the future?

Comment: Most welcome! Not in the short term.

Comment: But can you tell me why? It doesn't make any sense in my perspective...

Comment: Any news on this?

Comment: @MinhazKazi is BigQuery backfill in place? What alternatives are in place? Opening a ticket to GCP asking a point extraction of what is missing is a viable solution?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there isn't a direct, native feature within Google Cloud Platform or Google Analytics 4 (GA4) for backfilling historical data to BigQuery, as was available with Universal Analytics. This limitation means one must look for alternative methods to achieve similar outcomes.

A viable approach involves leveraging the Google Analytics Data API to fetch historical GA4 data and script-based automation to process and upload this data into BigQuery. This method requires:

Using the Google Analytics Data API: For extracting historical data from GA4.
Data Processing: Transforming the fetched data to align with BigQuery's schema requirements.
Automated Uploading: Scripting the upload process to BigQuery, ensuring data integrity and consistency.
This solution is not provided out of the box by Google Cloud Platform but can be implemented through custom scripting to fill the gap left by the absence of direct backfilling functionality in GA4.

For those looking for detailed guidance on this approach, resources and scripts are available in public repositories, such as one named "Backfill-GA4-to-BigQuery" on GitHub. These resources detail the process from fetching data using the API to processing and securely uploading it to BigQuery, offering a workaround to the backfilling challenge.

Comment: link to the repository : 
https://github.com/aliasoblomov/Backfill-GA4-to-BigQuery

Comment: I know that I could use the Data API, but as mentioned, it doesn't provide event-level data, so it doesn't meet my requirements.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no event_level API or solution available. and also I don't think Google sends granular data through third-party connectors in the future.